# Connect to Oracle 11g database through ODBC driver using python

Tags: python, database, oracle11g, odbc, pyodbc

I want to connect to the oracle 11g database through the ODBC Driver and not the ODBC client using python language. I have ODBC client installed on my system and my colleagues have ODBC Drivers installed on their systems. I wanted to know how to connect to the database which is in the cloud through ODBC Driver.

Through ODBC Client I used this:

**db=pyodbc.connect('Driver = " ", URL = " ", UserID = " ", Password = " " ')**

What would be the syntax if I have ODBC Driver.
If any package is required then please mention that also.

Comment: You appear to be confused. When you say that you connected "through ODBC Client" using pyodbc you were still connecting through an ODBC *driver*. So the other machines may have some other ODBC driver installed; you just need to find out what its name is and how to specify the parameters to connect. You'll need to RTFM for that.

Comment: Ok thanks!!  I was suspecting so as already Driver is mentioned in the statement. I'll try on other machines